# Giving the user a score as a % when they press the compare button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas

I have ZERO coding experience and am just trying to get into coding to see what is possible.

I have created a (VERY BASIC) website and am not even sure if I am using the correct language for this type of thing. What I have is a letter that the user can trace over and try again if they want to. I want to give them a score about how well they did tracing the letter and then have that displayed as a percentage to the user and have run into a lack of knowledge with how to implement this into my webpage.

The logic behind my brain says that they have to be able to at least do 75 percent of the straight line distances in order for it to be acceptable or else they could colour the whole page red or just press a dot over the letter for it to allow them to pass. Its kind of like a robot and age check thing. Anyway, here is my code that I have created so far:

```js
var lines = [];
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var isTracing = false;
var points = [];

function drawLetter() {
  var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
  var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
  var letterSize = 300;
  ctx.font = letterSize + "px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.fillText("A", centerX, centerY);
}
drawLetter();
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  x = e.offsetX;
  y = e.offsetY;
  isTracing = true;
  points.push([x, y]);
  updateTrace();
});
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  if (isTracing) {
    var newX = e.offsetX;
    var newY = e.offsetY;
    points.push([newX, newY]);
    updateTrace();
  }
});
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
  isTracing = false;
  lines.push(points);
  points = [];
});

function updateTrace() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawLetter();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(line[0][0], line[0][1]);
    for (var j = 1; j < line.length; j++) {
      var point = line[j];
      ctx.lineTo(point[0], point[1]);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  if (isTracing) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[0][0], points[0][1]);
    for (var k = 1; k < points.length; k++) {
      var p = points[k];
      ctx.lineTo(p[0], p[1]);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function compare() {
  var userPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
  var originalPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
  var diffPixels = new Uint8ClampedArray(userPixels.length);

  var numDiffPixels = pixelmatch(userPixels, originalPixels, diffPixels, canvas.width, canvas.height, {
    threshold: 0.1
  });

  var accuracy = (1 - numDiffPixels / (canvas.width * canvas.height)) * 100;
  document.getElementById("accuracy").textContent = "Accuracy: " + accuracy.toFixed(2) + "%";

  // Draw the differences on the canvas
  var diffCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  diffCanvas.width = canvas.width;
  diffCanvas.height = canvas.height;
  var diffCtx = diffCanvas.getContext("2d");
  var diffImageData = diffCtx.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);
  diffImageData.data.set(diffPixels);
  diffCtx.putImageData(diffImageData, 0, 0);
  document.body.appendChild(diffCanvas);

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: blue;
}

canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Trace the letter A</h1>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<button id="refreshButton" onclick="refreshPage()">Try Again</button>
<button id="compareButton" onclick="compare()">Compare</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixelmatch/4.0.2/pixelmatch.min.js">
```

This is my first experience with code and my first attempt to do something like this. Your patience and understanding are appreciated.

I just want to return the result of how well the user traced the letter as a percentage that the user can see.

Comment: I see it has been edited a little. Would this now work? It doesnt seem to work for me when I run it in VS Code.